# Object Mode shows odd Jitter on Mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects, error, object-mode

I am working off of the blender 2.83, I started a render and then stopped it to fix a mesh issue. When I returned to object mode I was greeted with this lovely disconcerting sight.

I have done the basics of turning blender on and off, clearing material caches, changing render modes. turning off layer....ect.

Any help would be appreciated, but please someone tell me my file isn't corrupted

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Appears to be z fighting, _ie_ two faces overlapping each other.

Comment: I would agree if that were the case all around, but the inside of the object has no overlapping planes and it is still appearing?  It also appears when I create a new plane on its own?

Comment: hello please share your object: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Are some normals backwards and you have backface culling on??

Answer (score 1):

If there are no mesh issues, overlapping faces etc. and it also appears when creating new faces, try the following:

In *3D Viewport*, press <kbd>N</kbd>, to open the Sidebar, go to *View > Clip Start / End* and change the values to e.g. 0.001 and 1000.

Sometimes these issues appear when you have imported an object which is very large or very small in Blender because of different unit systems or similar reasons, and when you are zooming in or out on the object or change the clipping to make it visible this strange behaviour can occur.

Not sure if this is the case with your file, but I get this error every once in a while.

Comment: Hello Gordon,  Sorry to say this did not resolve my issue, it still persists. My clip start is . 001mm and End is 1000000000mm. My friend suggested it could be a graphics card issue.  I am using a GeForce RTX 270,  so I really hope it is not my graphics card, but I am not putting it out of the question. I updated today and it still has not effect.

Answer (score 0):

For all people with jitter problems, change *Clip Start* from 0.01mm for something bigger, like 0.11mm.